# Find the sum of digits of n+1,n+2.... when sum of digits of n is given

Tags: java, algorithm, math, sum, digits

We can easily compute the sum of digits of a given number but is there any mathematical formula or pattern we can use to determine the sum of next numbers without having to sum all the digits again and again?

For example

```
Sum of 1234 = 1+2+3+4 = 10
Sum of 1235 = 1+2+3+5 = 11
Sum of 1236 = 1+2+3+6 = 12
```

I can see some kind of pattern here but unable come up with any efficient math algorithm.

I use below method to calculate the sum of digits:

```
public int sum(long n) {  
    int sum = 0;   
    while (n != 0) {    
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;  
    }  
    return sum;  
}
```

Which works fine but it is CPU intensive.  I want to do this much faster.  If I have a sequence of numbers, say `10->19` I should only have to count the digits for 10, then add one for each up to 19.

Is there any efficient way to calculate the sum of digits in numbers if I already have the sum of previous numbers?

Comment: Maybe this is a question for the [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/) Q&A.

Comment: This is not a homework.I came across this while working on another problem.@Sujay I have updated my question with some methods which I use currently.  @mathematician1975 sorry for the bad description of problem,i thought its straight forward problem.I have updated the question with some more details to explain it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DigitSum(n+1) = DigitSum(n) + 1 - (9 * NumberOfEndingZeros(n+1))
```

---

If you want to find not the digitsums of `t` consecutive numbers but the sum of the digitsums of `t` consecutive numbers (n+1, n+2, ..., n+t), it's simpler.

```
Sum(DigitSum(i)) for i = n+1 to n+t = a(n+t) - a(n)
```

where `a(i)` is the [A037123](http://oeis.org/A037123) sequence from the Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, which has several formulas. I think this will be quite fast:

```
a(n) = (1/2) * ( (n+1) * (n - 18 * sum{k>0, floor(n/10^k)} )
               + 9 * sum{k>0, (1+floor(n/10^k))*floor(n/10^k)*10^k}
               )
```

Comment: This was the solution I was about to suggest.

Comment: Nice answer. And I believe finding the number of ending zeros can be done in `O(loglogn)` worst case, using binary search to find the first non-zero digit

Comment: Though linear search will also be O(loglogn) *average* case, I believe.

Comment: Thanks all for your responses.@ypercube,@Peter and @amit You Guys are really awesome!

Answer (score 5):

The fastest way would be to extract each digit and add it as you go.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    // check values
    int runs = 1000000;
    for (int i = 100; i < runs; i++) {
        int sum = sumDigits(i - 1);
        int sum1 = sumDigits(i);
        int sum2 = sumDigits(sum, i);
        if (sum1 != sum2) throw new AssertionError(i + ": " + sum1 + " != " + sum2);
    }
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
        int sum = sumDigits(i);
        // prevent optimising away.
        if (sum < 0) throw new AssertionError();
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("sumDigits took an average of %,d ns%n", time / runs);
    long start2 = System.nanoTime();
    int lastSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
        int sum = sumDigits(lastSum, i);
        lastSum = sum;
        // prevent optimising away.
        if (sum < 0) throw new AssertionError();
    }
    long time2 = System.nanoTime() - start2;
    System.out.printf("sumDigits using previous value took an average of %,d ns%n", time2 / runs);

    long large = Long.MAX_VALUE - runs - 1;

    long start3 = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
        int sum = sumDigits(large + i);
        // prevent optimising away.
        if (sum < 0) throw new AssertionError();
    }
    long time3 = System.nanoTime() - start3;
    System.out.printf("sumDigits took an average of %,d ns%n", time3 / runs);
    long start4 = System.nanoTime();
    int lastSum2 = sumDigits(large);
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
        int sum = sumDigits(lastSum2, large + i);
        lastSum2 = sum;
        // prevent optimising away.
        if (sum < 0) throw new AssertionError();
    }
    long time4 = System.nanoTime() - start4;
    System.out.printf("sumDigits using previous value took an average of %,d ns%n", time4 / runs);

}

public static int sumDigits(long n) {
    int sum = 0;
    do {
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    } while (n > 0);
    return sum;
}

public static int sumDigits(int prevSum, long n) {
    while (n > 0 && n % 10 == 0) {
        prevSum -= 9;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return prevSum + 1;
}
```

prints

```
sumDigits took an average of 32 ns
sumDigits using previous value took an average of 10 ns
sumDigits took an average of 79 ns
sumDigits using previous value took an average of 7 ns
```

For large values, it can save around 70 ns. It add some complexity to your code. You have to use the first sumDigit to bootstrap the sum because you can't count all the way from 1 to 10^18.

Comment: Good answer (+1 from me), but are you sure it is _the_ fastest way? :-)

Comment: Its not always the fastest way, but it is the most straight forward and most likely to work. When you get down to small methods like this, the only way to know for sure is to compare in a micro-benchmark and I suspect the difference isn't worth worrying about.

Comment: I think you miss the issue at hand in the question - the OP wants to avoid re-calculating the sum of digits from scratch, and use knowledge from previous iterations (since he is summing consecutive numbers)

Comment: @amit true and he is also trying to find the fastest solution. I suspect that trying to reuse the old value is more trouble than it is worth i.e. it won't be much faster but it will be much more complicated.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:I am not sure. The solution suggested by ypercube scales much better (O(logn) vs O(loglogn)), and is pretty simple IMHO. I also believe the constants of his approach are pretty small. of course it does not matter if it does not happen for large numbers and/or tight loop - but I assume if it wasn't the case - the OP would have sticked to the naive solution (which he also suggested in the question)

Comment: P.S. Even not using binary search (but linear search) to find the number of taling zeros in @ypercube's solution will be O(loglogn) average case, I believe.

Comment: So I timed both approaches and using the previous value doesn't appear to help much. I suspect this is because extract all the digits of a number is a common pattern so the JVM optimises this quite well.

Comment: @amit very true. Actually the numbers I am trying to  sum are large (up to 10^18) so the naive method does not stand a chance.Also I can read the first digit as a String hence I am planning to use more efficient int sum(String num) method (which could easily calculate the sum by reading once char at a time) to calculate the sum of digits of first number.

Comment: @Peter: If the `n` is large enough, then the number of ending zeros does not have to be computed for all the consecutive numbers. That may improve efficiency (although it will be more complicated)

Comment: @WebHrushi: Don't use `String` to represent your numbers. If they are too big for `int`s use `long`s, and if it is also not enough, use `BigInteger`s. I believe it is already optimized, and it will definetly save you a lot of implementation time.

Comment: @WebHrushi You can't calculate the sum of the first number around 10^18 with this method.

Comment: @WebHrushi Using String will cost you far more than you could hope to save.

Comment: My micro-benchmark showed: `298 ns` VS `257 ns` (more then 10% difference) when setting initial i as `Long.MAX_VALUE/10` (and changing the iterator to `long` of course. I doubt this value can be statistically proven though.

Comment: @Peter true..point taken.I used above naive method just to represent the approach. Off course with the larger numbers I need to use appropriate   holders.

Answer (score 1):

Lets denote the sum of digits of a number `n` is `s(n)`

`s(49) = 13`

`s(94) = 13`

but `49+1 = 50` which `s(50) = 5`, while `94+1 = 95` which `s(95) = 14`.  So if you were only given that the sum of digits of `n` is 13, you have at least two different possible answers for the sum of the digits of `n+1`.  *You need some additional information about n*.

I do think a key is knowing that if n ends in a 9, `s(n+1)` will be at most s(n) - 9.  (Ah, that's where ypercube's answer comes in.)  So if you have xxxx9 (where the last x is anything but 9),  `s(xxxx9 + 1) = s(xxxx9) - 9 + 1`.  If you have xxx99, `s(xxx99 + 1) = s(xxx99) - 18 + 1`, etc.

So what might speed this up is if you count all the 10s, 100s, thousands, etc. in your range.

(Again, I see ypercube has beat me to the punch).  It would appear that's what the formula for  A037123 does exactly that (but from 0 to n).  (Lets call that `a(n)`)

So finally, since you're  wanting the sum of the sum of digits from n to n+r, and *not* the sum from 1 to n, we need to see if we can derive a formula for sum of the sum of digits for a range `ss(n,n+r)`

*That* would appear to be simply

`ss(n,n+r) = a(n+r) - a(n-1)`

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula from **[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digit_sum)**:
[image: This is the formula]

This is my implementation in Java:

```
public static int digitSum(int x) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, (int) Math.log10(x)) // From zero to the number of digits of x in base 10...
               .map(n -> (x % (int) Math.pow(10, n + 1) -  x % (int) Math.pow(10, n)) / (int) Math.pow(10, n)) // ...yield each digit...
               .sum() // and sum;
}
```